# How to mock the process.cwd() function with Jest?

Tags: mocking, jestjs

For a testcase I'm implementing I need to mock the `process.cwd()` function. In the testcase I have implemented it as follows:

```
process.cwd = jest.fn(() => '/base/dir')
```

When `process.cwd()` is called in the testcase it works as expected. In the module I'm testing it returns the original value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The `process` object in a `Jest` test isn't the real one, but it is also consistent during a test run so if your code requires `process` directly then you can still mock something like `process.cwd`:

code.js

```js
const process = require('process');

export const func = () => process.cwd();
```

code.test.js

```js
const process = require('process');
import { func } from './code';

test('func', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(process, 'cwd');
  spy.mockReturnValue('mocked value');

  expect(func()).toBe('mocked value');  // Success!
});
```

---

...it also works to mock the entire `process` module like this:

code.test.js

```js
import { func } from './code';

jest.mock('process', () => ({
  cwd: () => 'mocked value'
}));

test('func', () => {
  expect(func()).toBe('mocked value');  // Success!
});
```

---

(The issue they are talking about [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5146) is that you can't mock `process.cwd` during a test and have the mock affect other core Node.js module behavior like `path.resolve`).

Comment: Hi Brian, you are active man! Thx for the respons. I need it for exactly path.resolve :-(

Comment: yeah, I'm pretty active on the JavaScript unit testing questions :)  @nidkil

Comment: ah...sounds like you've got exactly the same issue as described in that link then.  I'll leave this answer here in case anyone is just trying to mock a direct call to `process.cwd`

Comment: Mocking the entire process object like in the second example doesnt work for me, but spyOn like in the first example appears to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is a known Jest [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5146).

> Yep; looks like it's caused by the fact that the process object on a test is not the real one, but a mocked version. Since all Node modules are required from the outer context (we tried fixing this in #4970, but we had to rollback as it's not mature enough yet), when you override process.cwd it's not the real one .

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

I create a `cwd.js` file whith just this

```js
module.exports = process.cwd()
```

Then, in every place I was before using `process.cwd()` now I use `require('path/to/cwd.js')`

And in the tests in order to mock it

```js
jest.mock('path/to/cwd', () => '/mocked/value')
```

It works, for my own code where I can change the way I use `process.cwd()`.

it won't work for any library that might use `process.cwd()`